# Regarding GPL/LGPL license about distributing the source code

Tags: open-source, licensing

If I make my code in GPL/LGPL license, does this mean that I have to release source to public/or as request ? Also, is there any opensource license that doesn't require me to do release the source ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are under no obligation to automatically release GPL code.

You must release GPL code only if you are distributing the GPL code (in any form - compiled or otherwise) to others, and you are only obligated to release it to those you are distributing it to. You could have GPL code that you sold and released to Microsoft and no one else - only they would have GPL rights to the source code, no one else. They could release it to anyone they like, of course. GPLv3 adds in some stuff about software as a service, as well.

If you don't want to release the source at all, why on earth would you want to call it "open source"? Use a normal proprietary license if you've got proprietary code.

Comment: I ask because I confuse a little bit after I read them. Especially GPL/LGPL, which seems to make everyone insane when they are about to include it into their codebase. I want to release the source code but I am just wonder if I have to if I'm under opensource license.

Comment: If you want to release it, why does it matter if you're required to release it?

Comment: Because I'm in some kind of academic hell with some (stupid) restrictions/rules about how and when to release the source code. Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll go for LGPL or maybe apache license.